# Place SAML SSO certificate in Non gallery

Tags: node.js, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I have an **SSO certificate** created in Azure. I want to place it in my application (Non gallery). How to please do Single sign-on. Please help. I am new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Good decription [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications#step-3-manage-the-saml-signing-certificate).

Generally, there is no need to do this.

When you create a SAML application, the certificate used to sign the outgoing token is automatically generated.

Azure AD does not check signed requests so no need to import the client certificate.

The exception is when you want to [encrypt the SAML token](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/howto-saml-token-encryption).